# What is the path to a Virtual Memory file created in python?

Tags: python, path, filesystems, fs, virtual-memory

I'm trying to create a virtual XML file, copy some content to it, then access through parsing. It may be simple; but every path that I'm trying to use ( like `'mem://mem_test.xml'` or `'{}'.format(mem_file)` ) are not working.

What path should I use to access a file in the Virtual Memory?

```py
import fs
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et

mem_fs = fs.open_fs('mem://')
os_fs = fs.open_fs(".")
mem_file = mem_fs.open('mem_test.xml', 'rw')
fs.copy.copy_file(os_fs, 'test.xml', mem_fs, 'mem_test.xml')
tree = Et.parse('[string with path to mem_test]')
root = tree.getroot()
mem_fs.close()
```

Comment: Have you found the answer to this? I'm looking for the save thing.

Comment: @LuísHenriqueMartins I had to do a workaround using "with ... as ... :"

Comment: @YuriWincheAchermann would you share the workaround code, please?

Comment: Hi, @Peter. I just posted an answer with the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found:

Created a class to deal with the temp objects

```
class TEMP(object):

def __init__(self, original_path):
    self.original_path = original_path

def __enter__(self):
    temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
    base_path = os.path.basename(self.original_path)
    self.path = os.path.join(temp_dir, base_path)
    shutil.copy2(self.original_path, self.path)
    return self.path

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    os.remove(self.path)
```

In the code pipeline for every routine that requested to access the temp file, instead of reaching through the path, I referenced the temporary path using a "with ... as" structure

```
with TEMP("file.example") as temp_path:
    doc = method_that_requires_the_path(temp_path)
```